# Error when trying to accept a native js popup with Codeception and Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, codeception

I am building a test for a Laravel project. The test has to check for some JS interactions. The test is simple, on user click a popup should appear if Terms and Conditions are not accepted. I am using phantomJS with the acceptance test config.

```
modules:
  enabled:
    - WebDriver
  config:
    PhpBrowser:
        url: 'http://eo3.localhost/'
    WebDriver:
        url: 'http://eo3.localhost/'
        browser: phantomjs
```

The test code:

```
$I->seeElement('.free-bets #claim-button');
$I->click('#claim-button');
$I->seeInPopup("Please accept t&c");
```

The test works fine untill the last point, on the last point it throws this error

```
  [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverException] JSON decoding of remote response failed.
Error code: 4
```

I am following [this](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver)

Comment: What are the `Codeception` and `PhantomJS` versions?

Comment: Codeception is 2.1.2 (latest I believe) and phantomJS is 2.0.0

Comment: It is a known issue in phantomJS and will be fixed in 2.0.1 more info: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12506

Comment: @JarekJakubowski great news, do you have any time approximation of when the new version will be released?